# Display featured posts from a specific WordPress category

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have some code written which displays the latest 5 posts from a specific category however I can't work out how to make it display the latest 5 posts from that category that are marked as featured only. By featured I mean the post has been stickied, so basically it will display the 5 posts from each category that have been stickied.

```
<ul id="index-blog">

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=whats-on&showposts=5' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

<div class="index-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(50,50), array ('class' =>   'alignleft')); ?></div>
<div class="indexblog-title"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink()      ?>"                    rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<li>
   <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
</li>

<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sticky=get_option('sticky_posts');
$query_args=array(
'post__in' => $sticky,
'category__in'=>array($category)
 );
$the_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
```

You can get the top 5 sticky posts using rsort and array_slice as shown in http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

Comment: Gave that a try still having no luck

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the other answer is that introduces a variable - `$category` - that you have to first populate.

Here's the revised code, including how to populate the variable:

```
<ul id="index-blog">
    <?php $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'whats-on' );
          $args = array(
              'cat'       => $category_id,
              'post__in'  => get_option('sticky_posts'),

          );
    ?>
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
        // Fix some markup issues here - the children of `ul` elements must be `li` elements....
        <li>
            <div class="index-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(50,50), array ('class' =>   'alignleft')); ?></div>
            <div class="indexblog-title"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink()      ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            <div class="excerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```